# How do you isolate the id of an object to show specified data related to that id?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, filter

I have a note pad app I am building, trying to figure out how to isolate a specific id to show the data in the object related to that id.

the goal is to click on note one and show data for that note only, like wise click on note two and show the data for note two.

Here is my code, I am some what new to vue and javascipt

```js
<script>
import AddNoteButton from "./components/AddNoteButton.vue";
import NoteList from "./components/NoteList.vue";
import SaveButton from "./components/SaveButton.vue";
// import ShowNote from "./components/ShowNote.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    NoteList,
    AddNoteButton,
    SaveButton,
    // ShowNote
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editorIsOpen: false,
      readingNote: false,
      openNote: false,
      showNote: true,
      props: {
        note: {
          required: true,
        },
      },
      selectedNotes: [],
      notes: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "1st Note",
          body: "Body of note 1",
          date: "10/17/20",
          isSelected: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "2nd Note",
          body: "Body of note 2",
          date: "11/17/20",
          isSelected: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
    // computed: {
    // filterNotes: function() {
    //  return this.notes.filter(note => note.title.indexOf(this.title))
    // }
  },
  methods: {
    openNewEditor() {
      this.editorIsOpen = !this.editorIsOpen;
    },
    readNote(note) {
      console.log("readNote: ", note);
      this.readingNote = note;
    },
    addSelectedNote(id, body) {
      console.log('note:' , this.noteId)
      this.selectedNotes.unshift({
        noteId: id,
        noteBody: body,
      })
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="notepad-container h-75 w-75">
      <header class="header d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h4>Light Notepad v1</h4>
      </header>

      <section class="notepad-content" v-if="editorIsOpen === false">
        <note-list
          v-for="note in notes"
          :key="note.id"
          :note="note"
          @open-note="readNote(showNote)"
        ></note-list>
        <add-note-button @open-editor="openNewEditor"></add-note-button>
      </section>

      <section class="notepad-editor" v-if="editorIsOpen === true">
        <save-button></save-button>
      </section>

      <!-- notes section -->
      <section v-if="readingNote === true" class="">
        <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
          {{ selectedNotes.noteId }} 
          <!-- <show-note :note="note"
                @open-note="openNote"></show-note> -->
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "noteList",
  emits: ["open-note"],
  props: {
    note: {
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    openNote() {
      this.$emit("open-note");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
    <template>
  <div>
    <b-list-group>
      <b-list-group-item class="select" button @click="openNote(note.id)"
        >{{ note.title }} - {{ note.date }}
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer, I got it from the Vue.js forum:

For the sake of simplicity let’s assume you want to only select one note at a time with this event:

```
@open-note="readNote(note.id)"
```

We then want to get that specific note from the array

```
// ...
selectedNote: null,
// ...
readNote(id) {
  this.selectedNote = this.notes.find(note => note.id === id);
}
```

then within your template to display it:

```
<section v-if="selectedNote">
  {{ selectedNote.title }} 
</section>
```

As you can see, we no longer need to store a isSelected property on the note and we can reduce the state booleans by just checking if the selectedNote is not falsly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your component note-list are. But have you tried to pass the note as parameter?

```
<section class="notepad-content" v-if="editorIsOpen === false">
        <note-list
          v-for="note in notes"
          :key="note.id"
          :note="note"
          @open-note="readNote(note)" //this line 
        ></note-list>
        <add-note-button @open-editor="openNewEditor"></add-note-button></section>
```

Comment: what do you mean as a parameter, also I added the component for note-list above

Comment: My guess, was to change showNote to note. This @open-note="readNote(showNote)" to @open-note="readNote(note)"

Comment: tried that before, nothing shows up on click, I need to isolate the id of the note to show the specific data of that note when clicked, I am thinking i need to filter the array or write a turnery data bind to grab the info, when i tried that both notes appeared on click and both were changed

Comment: In the note list, you are open getting the id as follow: openNote(note.id). Try to pass that id in the method were you emit the event: 
```openNote(id)  {  this.$emit("open-note", id);}, ```. You will have to remove the show note in you parent component ```@open-note="readNote(showNote)"```. And add it on the readNote: ``` readNote(id) {
     //now you can filter the note here
    },```

Comment: how would i filter i need to do a data bind i don't think that is possible where you are directing me to do the filter, thank you for trying to help me